# How do I make a HTML button tag unclickable after one click?

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, anchor

Currently assigned the task of creating a website which uses python to visualize a network. With this, after clicking a button, the python script will run off of specific parameters the user sets. To avoid a huge load request, we only want the user to click the button once, and not be able to run the script multiple times. The idea we came up with was having the button be clicked once, and then after the one request, become disabled(until they refresh the page, although I know they can just run it again, but we will discuss that problem once we get there). We are currently using an anchor tag to call upon the python script using PHP as well. I believe that since we are using an anchor tag, we may have to change the href attribute of the anchor tag so that it just doesn't run the python script numerous times, making the button useless even if its clickable.

We've tried using JavaScript functions:

```
let toggleVisual = false;

let hideVisual = function() {
  let visual = document.getElementsById('visual');

  if (toggleVisual = false) {
    visual.disabled = true;
    toggleVisual = true;
  }
}
```

and more JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('form-button').onclick = function () {
    this.disabled = true;
}
```

and even some HTML:

```
<a href="?run=true" onclick="return false;"><button  id="form-button" class="visualize-btn">Visualize</button></a>
```

PHP code calling python script:

```
   <?php
   if (isset($_GET["run"])) {
      $output = shell_exec('sh test.sh');
      echo "<pre>$output</pre> works";
    }
   ?>
```

I expect that when I click the button to run the script, the button (or anchor tag) will become disabled, ensuring that the python script won't run multiple times.

Comment: `if (toggleVisual = false)`   is an assignment...not comparison. Use `===`

Comment: This makes sense, but after putting it into the JS code and putting in the correct id's, still doesnt seem to work.

Comment: `<button> ` inside `<a>` doesn't make sense either...don't think it's even valid html. Certainly isn't from accessibility standpoint

Comment: Would it be more efficient to make an `<input>` tag?

Comment: Not inside an `<a>` ..no

Comment: Not inside an `<a>` tag, by itself as `<input type="button" name="run" value="true">`  inside a `<form>` tag, with a specific ID linking it to the JS? Remember, I do need this to communicate to the PHP so it can run the script on the first click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! You were close.. Check out the [onclick()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event, you'll probably like it. A simple code based on your first attempt would be something like:

```html
<button id="form-button" class="visualize-btn" onclick="doSomething();">Visualize</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var wasClicked = false;
function doSomething() {
    if(wasClicked) { return; }
    wasClicked = true;

   // Your code here
   alert('Hello world!');
}
</script>
```

Best of luck with your website!

Comment: Yes! This solves my issue on making the button disabled, but since we remove the `<a>` tag, it can no longer communicate to the PHP code. Is there a way to communicate to PHP using either $_GET or $_POST methods?

Comment: Sure! A simple method would be using [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), check out the example codes on that page. Put the code (as simple as `fetch('https://example.com');`) where the alert() is and it should be called once in the background. :)